# Retrieve the username which got authenticated by the apache

Tags: apache, perl

I have an apache 2.2 setup with LDAP auth enabled. The html form in the front end takes some values and processes them using perl script in the background. Is there a way I can get the username which is submitting the values in that perl script. I am planning to track who is doing what(with the values they submit) in a more better way in a file than the usual access_log.

I tried using the below in my perl script, but no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
my $userId = $_SERVER['AUTHENTICATE_SAMACCOUNTNAME'];
print " I am $userId";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be confusing Perl with PHP :-)

The usual way for a CGI program to get hold of the authenticated username, is though `$ENV{REMOTE_USER}`. But your reference to AUTHENTICATE_SAMACCOUNTNAME confuses me slightly. You might try `$ENV{AUTHENTICATE_SAMACCOUNTNAME}`.

Comment: Yes You are right. I was not getting ENV part on a google search. So just tried the way PHP does it. :P But got that later. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Googling for Perl can be (as you have found) a bit hit and miss. That's why we have the [Perl Search Engine](http://search.perlhacks.com/).